# After a MongoDB update operation access the up-to-date state of data (and not before)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The following code deletes a user's review (from a post) and returns the result message to the client:

```
// delete the review
const operationResult=await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id:request.params.id}, 
  {$pull:{reviews:{userid:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(request.params.userid)}}});
  
result.status(200).json({ message: 'review deleted', post:operationResult });
```

While the post is being deleted from the Database, the data stored in `operationResult` (which is passed to the client) is actually the state of the post *before* the update is applied. Thus although the reviewed is deleted, it's still in the variable `operationResult`. Is there anyway to execute a Database operation in node.js and store the result of the post in `operationResult` variable `after` the update is applied?